# past + that + are/were tense question

Tags: grammar, verbs

Teachers

In this sentense should I change are to were? even though the rainforests keep disappearing?

> Did you hear that the rainforests `are` disappearing rapidly?

Thank you

Comment: Did you hear that he understands the question? [in general] Did you hear that he understood the question? [yesterday].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rainforests are continuing to disappear now, it's present tense so **are** is correct. If they stopped disappearing at some point in the past (or if they have fully disappeared), then you would change it to **were**, as it's past tense at that point.